# Running Batch Build Pyramids from subfolders

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have a question that someone might help me. I have set up 10 folders for each office. I have set up a sub-folders that holds the landsat 8. I worked on landsat 8 in ERDAS and since I am done doing that.

Now I need to run about 100 Imagine files to run batch Build Pyramids for ArcGIS 10.1 but I want something much quicker.

I want to use Model Builder to run Build Pyramids for all of the 10 office landsat 8 sub folders ?

For example   Folder =    Office name

```
          subfolder = landsat8

                      name of landsat.img
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Erdas to build the pyramids.  Not only can you build pyramids in batch mode using multiple cores, but you will avoid the ArcGIS/Erdas pyramid incompatibility issue (i.e. pyramids built in ArcGIS are not recognized by Erdas).  However, if you need to build pyramids using ArcGIS, you will want to make sure to check the "Recursive" option.  This will allow you to recursively iterate through all of you folders and sub-folders.

[image]

This is the Erdas approach I would recommend:

1. Open pyramids GUI in Erdas: Manage Data tab > Pyramids & Statistics
2. Add a Landsat scene
3. Check "Compute Pyramid Layers"
4. Open the batch window by selecting "Batch" at the bottom of the GUI
5. In the Batch Command Editor, choose variables: "one or more inputs,
   one output"
6. Select all of your files using "Add Files..."
7. Run it by selecting "Submit..."
8. Choose how ever many simultaneous processes you would like (Check
   your core count first)
9. Select "OK"